# How to test a graphql upload mutation with additional parameters in laravel lighthouse

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-lighthouse

As the title states, I want to be able to test the upload of a file using the available scalar while also providing additional parameters to the same mutation. The documentation provides a helper on how to test this [Lighthouse docs simulating file uploads](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.16/testing/phpunit.html#simulating-file-uploads). But my mutation also needs some additional dynamic parameters for the test. But I can't figure out how to provide these additional parameters. An example of my current setup:

```
$response = $this->multipartGraphQL(['operations' => {
   "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) {registerUser(email: $email, files: [$file]) {courseRegistrationFiles{id}}}",
   "variables": {"file": null}
}', 'map' => '{"0": ["variables.file"]}'], [
   '0' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('document.pdf', 100)
]);
```

A few additional notes the $email should be represented using a faked email address, this is done in the line above this snippet. At first, I imagined that I had to provide the email variable within the same brackets as where I define the uploadeFile::fake() but this lead to the error that stated that parameters within this portion of the method should be of the type `UploaedFile`. After that I've also tried simply adding them to the map/variables portions but this lead to the param being null.

Answer (score 1):

Now is a bit different, you need 3 array params like:

```
$operations = [
    'operationName' => 'upload',
    'query' => 'mutation upload ($file: Upload!) {
                    upload (file: $file)
                }',
    'variables' => [
        'file' => null,
    ],
];

$map = [
    '0' => ['variables.file'],
];

$file = [
    '0' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('test.pdf', 500),
];

$this->multipartGraphQL($operations, $map, $file);
```

Here are docs to help you out: https://lighthouse-php.com/5.2/testing/phpunit.html#simulating-file-uploads